# $.getJSON is not saving data into global variable/object, which is local there

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a file data3.json:

```
{
"street":"Oslo West 555",
"age":33,
"phone":"555 1234567"
}
```

I want to read this file with JavaScript (and JQuery) and store the values into an object.

I have the HTML file (same directory):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>JSON Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>
Name: <span id="jname"></span><br />
Age: <span id="jage"></span><br />
Address: <span id="jstreet"></span><br />
Phone: <span id="jphone"></span><br />
</p>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
var JSONObject = {};

function add(key, value)  {
    JSONObject[key] = value;
}

add("name", "John Johnson");

$.getJSON('data3.json', function(data) {
        $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
            console.log(JSONObject);
            console.log(key + ": " + val);
            JSONObject[key] = val;
        });
});
$("#jname")[0].innerHTML    = JSONObject.name;
$("#jage")[0].innerHTML = JSONObject.age;
$("#jstreet")[0].innerHTML  = JSONObject.street;
$("#jphone")[0].innerHTML   = JSONObject.phone;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In Browser I get:

```
Name: John Johnson
Age: undefined
Address: undefined
Phone: undefined
```

In console I get:

```
street: Oslo West 555
Object { street="Oslo West 555"}
age: 33
Object { street="Oslo West 555", age=33}
phone: 555 1234567
Object { street="Oslo West 555", age=33, phone="555 1234567"}
```

I have tested adding value inside the function with the function add(...), which works fine.
Inside of $.getJSON the variable became local...

How can force $.getJSON to add the data to my variable JSONObject?

Comment: `$.getJSON` is async. You should read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Answer (score 1):

```
$.getJSON('data3.json', function(data) {

     JSONObject = data;

     $("#jname").html(JSONObject.name);
     $("#jage").html(JSONObject.age);
     $("#jstreet").html(JSONObject.street);
     $("#jphone").html(JSONObject.phone); 

});
```

Comment: Thank for reply. Your solution works to get the data into HTML, but I want to keep the data also in the variable JSONObject.

Comment: Not it is not, if i try:
$.getJSON('data3.json', function(data) {
  JSONObject = data;
 });

 $("#jage")[0].innerHTML  = JSONObject.age;
 $("#jstreet")[0].innerHTML = JSONObject.street;
 $("#jphone")[0].innerHTML = JSONObject.phone;

Comment: no need of using array index $("#jage")[0]'. a span element with 'jage' id can be accessed like $("#jage") and value can be changed through $("#jage").html('');

Comment: if you run, alert(JSON.stringify(JSONObject)); you can see those values.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but try to use the content after });, outside of $.getJSON.